# Runtime User Privilege Management ColdFusion on CentOS cPanel

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd

I'm needing to understand the correct workflow for managing permissions to allow the ColdFusion 9 runtime user {coldfusion} to have access to user accounts.

The germane elements ...

Centos 5.8
WHM 11.32.4 cPanel
EasyApache
ColdFusion 9

ColdFusion 9 is installed and proxying connections to jrun server through Apache via mod_jrun22 ...

On the cPanel side - Apache user are username:usergroup in vhost containers ...

Apache is running as the nobody account and through suExec runs as the account user specified in the vhost container ... However, this doesn't seem to be an option for the ColdFusion user ...

So the basic question is how do I give permissions to the ColdFusion user account to run the same way the Apache account does?

Answer (score 0):

Create the `www` group and add the `coldfusion` user to that group along with `apache`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the java application server ( tomcat for eg:) to run under under privilege .

This was one of the main problems when I build a plugin for cpanel (ndeploy.in) which provides railo( a coldfusion alternative) and I ended up creating certain folders like WEB-INF and logs in the application_root using root privilege .Ofcourse if the CF app has to write something to the application_root that folder must have a 777 permission or write permission for nobody at the least ;same as you would have when running mod_php with nobody privilege.